# Bot Framework Skill using NodeJS Virtual Assistant template - not able to add to PVA

Tags: node.js, typescript, botframework, power-virtual-agents

As the title says I have created the [skill using the virtual assistant template](https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/skills/tutorials/create-skill/typescript/1-intro/) and deployed it in Azure. The skill bot works as expected when tested as a standalone bot with an emulator. When I tried to add the skill to the Power Virtual Agent bot it fails with an error - "**This skill has not allow listed your bot**".

I have already added the PVA bot's app Id to the skill bot's appSettings.json as below and tried with the wild card as "*" still not able to add the skill. Any help?

```
 "allowedCallers": ["5a089b57-xxx-4a2c-xxx-xxxxde5ddd"]
```

Both PVA root bot and Skill bot are in same tenant.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/skill-pva?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#validation-performed-during-registering-a-skill). The error you are getting is at the last with the validation step and the mitigation details.

You will need to check if your bot has been added to the skill's allow list. To configure a skill for use in Power Virtual Agent, follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-virtual-agents/configuration-add-skills#configure-a-skill-for-use-in-power-virtual-agents) documentation.

Comment: As I mentioned already the skill bot's appSettings.json has been updated with a wild card and also tried with the PVA root bot's ID.